Connect IP camera to switch to Ubuntu laptop, no external router
I have a Swann IP Camera connected to a PoE unmanaged switch. The switch is connected directly to my Ubuntu laptop with an ethernet cable.  There is no wifi involved and no router - no other devices exist (the laptop does have a wifi interface, but it's not connected to wifi). I'm not trying to get internet access - I just want to use the camera through the laptop.
Do I need to set up my laptop as a router using software or is there some other way?

Ubuntu 22.04
Switch is Netgear Unmanaged Switch (GS108LP)
Camera is Swann SWNHD-880CAM

-- UPDATE --
I hooked up an old router to the switch and it discovered the IP camera at 172.16.1.x
After reconfiguring the router to use 172.16.1.* subnet (instead of 192.168.1.x), I was able to connect to the camera from my laptop as the laptop was now also on the same subnet, but only by using the router.
How can I do the same, but without the router? i.e. just using my laptop connected directly to the switch.

How is your laptop's Ethernet port setup, i.e. what subnets have you tried? Did you try to snoop the network, e.g. use Wireshark? If the camera is issuing DHCP requests for an active IP address, then you could setup a DHCP server/daemon on your laptop to satisfy this requirement, and that should make the camera visible and active. Alternatively, configuring the camera with a static IP address would be simpler if that's possible. FYI ifconfig is only going to inform you of local network interfaces, and nothing about what is connected.

@sawdust Updated the question with some more information. Thanks

Configure your laptop inteface with any network you would like to have for the connection cam - laptop using whatever network manager you are using or simply by:
sudo ip addr add 192.168.100.1/30 dev eth0
sudo ip link set up eth0

(Replace eth0 with whatever you interface is. The above is a minimal full (having network address and broadcast address) network for two host (4 ip addresses in total). Observe that if you do it like above using ip addr + ip link it won't last over reboots ... so configure it in you network manager instead (netplan / ifupdown / NetworkManager / wicd / or whatever you are using ... I think netplan is default in Ubuntu.)
With the laptop connected to the internet install a suitable dhcpd (in this example we are using the isc-dhcpd):
sudo apt install isc-dhcp-server

Configure the dhcpd for you cam-nw:
-- /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf --
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
subnet 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.252 {
  range 192.168.100.2 192.168.100.2;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.252;
  option routers 192.168.100.1; # this should not be necessary but some appliances expects the router to be set
}

-- /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server --
INTERFACESv4="eth0"

Now restart the dhcpd
sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service

When your cam renews it's lease (restart it) it should get 192.168.100.2 ...

Would there be any problem if I had the laptop at 172.16.1.1, the camera at 172.16.1.2 (which is where it seems to want to be anyway)?

no problem at all :-) just replace 192.168.100. with 172.16.1. in the above example ... if the camera is picky (some appliances is so badly implemented that they don't accept all netmasks you can use /24 (instead of /30) and 255.255.255.0 (instead of 255.255.255.252) ...
and finally it might be that the cam would expect to get DNS from the DHCP ... but unlikely that it don't accept the lease if it does not ... ut if so just add
option domain-name-servers 172.16.1.1; in the dhcpd subnet-block
or with any ip address
